# What is the default wait time in celery for re-queuing task when worker get killed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

I am using below options in task decorator to re-queue the task, when the worker get killed.

```
acks_late=True

reject_on_worker_lost=True
```

is there any option to reduce that wait time for re-queue?

**Below packages are installed.**

```
celery==4.3.0

kombu==4.6.3

amqp==2.3.2

billiard==3.5.0.4
```

**Expected:**

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#worker

given default for worker_lost_wait is 10s as per document.

> **No. of workers running**: 2
>
> **concurrency:** 1 (so two tasks in parallel)
>
> **Task behaviour:** Task will run for 40s and fail due to SoftTimeli

- Creating task using apply_async.

```
task = sample_celery_task.s(x=len(celery_async_result), y=0)
result = task.apply_async(soft_time_limit=40,
                                  queue=PIPELINE_QUEUE,
                                  retry=True,
                                  retry_policy={
                                      'max_retries': 1,
                                      'interval_start': 0,
                                      'interval_step': 0.2,
                                      'interval_max': 0.2,
                                  })
```

- Task

```
@app.task(acks_late=True, reject_on_worker_lost=True)
def sample_celery_task(x, y):
    result = x + y
    print(sample_celery_task.reject_on_worker_lost)
    print(sample_celery_task.acks_late)
    time.sleep(60)
    return result
```

**Result**

My assumption was as soon worker gets killed, task will be re-queue and run by some other available worker. But it gets re-queue approximately 1hr.

**Exception while killing worker**

> [2019-09-05 17:35:30,694: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-1] Pool process
>    error:
>   BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe') Traceback (most recent call last): 
>   File
>   "/Users/duraipandian/venv/with_line_profiler/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/pool.py",
>   line 362, in workloop
>       put((READY, (job, i, result, inqW_fd)))   File "/Users/duraipandian/venv/with_line_profiler/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/queues.py",
>   line 366, in put
>       self.send_payload(ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))   File "/Users/duraipandian/venv/with_line_profiler/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/queues.py",
>   line 358, in send_payload
>       self._writer.send_bytes(value)   File "/Users/duraipandian/venv/with_line_profiler/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/connection.py",
>   line 229, in send_bytes
>       self._send_bytes(m[offset:offset + size])   File "/Users/duraipandian/venv/with_line_profiler/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/connection.py",
>   line 455, in _send_bytes
>       self._send(header + buf)   File "/Users/duraipandian/venv/with_line_profiler/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/connection.py",
>   line 408, in _send
>       n = write(self._handle, buf) BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/duraipandian/venv/with_line_profiler/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/pool.py",
>   line 289, in **call**
>       sys.exit(self.workloop(pid=pid))   File "/Users/duraipandian/venv/with_line_profiler/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/pool.py",
>   line 370, in workloop
>       put((READY, (job, i, (False, einfo), inqW_fd)))   File "/Users/duraipandian/venv/with_line_profiler/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/queues.py",
>   line 366, in put
>       self.send_payload(ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))   File "/Users/duraipandian/venv/with_line_profiler/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/queues.py",
>   line 358, in send_payload
>       self._writer.send_bytes(value)   File "/Users/duraipandian/venv/with_line_profiler/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/connection.py",
>   line 229, in send_bytes
>       self._send_bytes(m[offset:offset + size])   File "/Users/duraipandian/venv/with_line_profiler/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/connection.py",
>   line 455, in _send_bytes
>       self._send(header + buf)   File "/Users/duraipandian/venv/with_line_profiler/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/connection.py",
>   line 408, in _send
>       n = write(self._handle, buf) BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Comment: Maybe all your workers were busy at the time you measured?

Comment: Yes, it was busy at the time of worker lose. But all other tasks are completed in 5 mins.

Comment: Yes, but you could have 10s of thousands of tasks that take 5m in the queue, before your task got re-queued, right?

Comment: I updated how i performed my testing. It will be helpful for others too. Thanks.